# Collision messed up due to bitmap

Tags: image, actionscript-3, collision-detection

So I have created a pseudo 3D collision system (is that what you call it?) in AS3(early version shown off [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVAU7Y0tc_I&feature=youtu.be&user=badfitz66) ), I was using a simple circle sprite for this, now I have changed to my own character image by doing

```
[Embed(source = 'Library/MChar.png')] private var MCharacter:Class;
```

and then making a variable for the character

```
public var Character = new MCharacter();
```

but since this thing is no longer a circle, I have absolutely no idea how to do collision (never done anything with AS3 except for some basic box2d stuff)

code for collision:

```
    for each (var wall in Walls)
    {
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x - hitRad+1, Character.y, true)) //col right
        {
            Character.x+=CharacterSpeed;
        }
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x + hitRad-1, Character.y, true)) //col left
        {
            Character.x-=CharacterSpeed;
        }
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x , Character.y - hitRad, true)) //col bottom
        {
            Character.y+=CharacterSpeed;
        }
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x, Character.y+hitRad-30, true)) //col top
        {
            Character.y -= CharacterSpeed;
        }
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x, Character.y+hitRad-0.01, true))  // col top #2
        {
            Top = true;
        }
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x - hitRad, Character.y, true) || wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x + hitRad, Character.y, true) || wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x , Character.y - hitRad-1, true))
        {
            Top = false;
        }
    }
```

sorry if you don't understand. I don't know how to explain it, as I mentioned earlier I'm brand new to AS3 (only know lua and python at the moment). The wall is also a bitmap but it's just a rectangle.

Comment: Try googling for **AS3 bitmap pixel collision detection** those keywords should help you. Afterwards you can update your question code to show your new attempt at pixel-precise collisions that someone can help you with (if still needed)

Comment: Could I change it to work like the collision in the video? I assume you mean Pixel Perfect Collision Detection.

Answer (score 0):

Try these links:

**[tut 1: Transparent PNG images](http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/02/03/using-hittestpoint-or-hittest-on-transparent-png-images/)**

**[tut 2 : HitTest Guide](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/HitTest-AS3-for-collision-detection-Flash-Actionscript-3/68594)**

As a start.. Try this code as found at: http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=90435

```
function ObjectsHit (mc1, mc2) : Boolean //returns a true or false as result
{
    var mc1bounds = mc1.getBounds(this);
    var mc2bounds = mc2.getBounds(this);
    var allintersections = (mc2bounds.intersection(mc1bounds)); 
    for (var xval:Number = allintersections.x; xval < allintersections.x + allintersections.width; xval ++ ) 
    {
        for (var yval:Number = allintersections.y; yval < allintersections.y + allintersections.height;yval ++ ) 
        {
            if (mc2.hitTestPoint(xval, yval, true) && mc1.hitTestPoint(xval, yval, true)) 
            {
                return(true);
            }
        }
    }

    return(false);
}
```

Whenever you want to run the function to test if two objects are touching, just add a line like below in your code:

`Top = ObjectsHit (mc1, mc2);` where mc1 and mc2 are the instance names of the testing objects. `Top` will become true or false depending on collision check result.

Comment: But that just makes it collide at the edge of all sides. I want to be able to go infront of the wall when colliding with bottom and behind it when colliding from the top. How can I do this?